# R: How is F statistic calculated in mgcv?

Tags: r, dataframe, mgcv

I have a simple GAM, with one smooth. When I run `summary()` or `anova.gam()` on the model, it gives me an F test for the significance of the smooth. However, it is unclear what dfs are being used to calculate the f distribution and p value.

I am trying to understand how the `mgcv` package in R determines the df in F tests on the significance of smooth terms. This is the equation given in General Additive Models: An Introduction with R" by Simon Woods:

[image: F ratio equation from "General additive models: an introduction with R" Simon Woods]

However, when I calculate the F ratio and p value manually, it does not line up with the values reported by the F test `mgcv` is doing. Similarly, I cannot use the F statistic the package gives me, nor any combination of the degrees of freedom available within the model (`model$df.residuals`, `model$df.null`, `model$edf`, etc) to produce the same p-value.

Any tips?

Here is the model output for the GAM I am trying to run in `mgcv`. I am trying to understand the df for the F test on `s(var)`.

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
response ~ s(var, k = 5)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.5698     0.3866    4.06 0.000412 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
         edf Ref.df    F p-value   
s(var) 3.522  3.868 5.05 0.00321 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.399   Deviance explained = 47.2%
GCV = 5.2809  Scale est. = 4.4849    n = 30
```

Comment: Providing your model output is less important than providing reproducible code. There could be an error in your manual calculation, or any number of things. You will likely get better, more accurate help by providing reproducible data and the code you have tied

Comment: Ultimately the calculation is done by `stats::stat.anova()`. Perhaps inspecting the R code of that funciton helps you to deepen your understanding.

Comment: @RicVillalba `stats::stat.anova()` isn't used here at all

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the definition of F from the *GLM* section of Simon's book (p. 109, 2nd edition), as that's not how the tests of smooths are computed. The details are in section 6.12 starting on p 304 of Simon's book (2nd edition), with section 6.12.1 covering the main points. This is all based on Simon's 2013 paper (http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2012/10/18/biomet.ass048).

The EDF needed for this test is the one in the `Ref.df` column, which is available in the `$edf1` component of the the fitted model object (you'll need to sum the relevant values for each smooth in the model - but here you have only one).

The actual computation of the test statistic is done via `mgcv:::testStat()`, so you can look there for the gory computational details.

Finally, the p value is not something you look up in a standard F distribution - it involves mixtures of chi-square distributions if I follow Simon's book after a quick skim of the relevant section.